# How to use UIScrollView with complex picture

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a complex picture . It consists of several layers. Each layer is a picture .
for example , background picture -> man picture -> gun picture -> foreground picture
I want drag and use pinch gesture with complex picture .
Can i do it with UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you make all the UIImageViews of your complex picture and put them in a UIScrollView (I'm assuming that you've tried this before asking your question?)

i.e from inside a view controller :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIImageView *i1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgoround.png"]] autorelease];
    UIImageView *i2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"man.png"]] autorelease];
    UIImageView *i3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gun.png"]] autorelease];

    UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]] autorelease];
    [v addSubview:i1];
    [v addSubview:i2];
    [v addSubview:i3];

    return v;
}
```

Comment: What i should return in this method ?                                  - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView